# Cake NuGetRestore Could not locate nuget.exe

Tags: nuget, cakebuild

I have created simple .NET5 console application which can be successfully run using "dotnet restore" and "dotnet run". Application is using one package Newtonsoft.Json.

I want to restore NuGet packages using NuGetRestore() but in result I get "Could not locate nuget.exe".
I am using Cake .NET Tool in version 1.1.0 and default configuration.

As far as I remember, previously when I was using Cake before version 1.0.0 nuget.exe was downloaded to 'tools' folder.

What am I missing? How to make sure nuget.exe is downloaded/provided by Cake?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order for the NuGet tool to be downloaded to the `tools` folder, you need to include the `NuGet.CommandLine` package in your Cake build script. e.g.

```
#tool nuget:?package=NuGet.CommandLine&version=5.9.1
```

Related info:

- [Example build.cake file referencing NuGet.CommandLine](https://github.com/augustoproiete/ExcelDnaPack-NuGet/blob/v1.1.1/build.cake#L1)
- [NuGet.exe related documentation](https://github.com/cake-build/cake/discussions/3271)

Answer (score 1):

Cake itself never did download nuget.exe. The [example bootstrapper for Cake Runner for .NET Framework](https://cakebuild.net/docs/running-builds/runners/cake-runner-for-dotnet-framework#bootstrapping-for-cake-runner-for.net-framework) does this in certain conditions. [Example bootstrapper for Cake .NET Tool](https://cakebuild.net/docs/running-builds/runners/dotnet-tool#getting-the-bootstrapper) does not download nuget.exe and you need to make yourself sure to have it available, either by updating the bootstrapper, using the [tool prepocessor directive](https://cakebuild.net/docs/writing-builds/preprocessor-directives/tool/nuget-provider) in your build script, or any other mechanism outside of Cake.